# MySQL blob: how to get just a subset of the stored data

Tags: mysql, blob

I would like to use MYSQL as a storage system for a huge number of files.
I would like to read/write just a portion of the data stored in a column (data is stored as bytes) so I don't have to load the entire file into the application (because it can be > than a GB).
So, in brief, I would like to have random read/write access in a blob column without loading the entire data into memory.
Are there functions available to perform these operations? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL treats [blobs the same as strings (more or less)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html):

> `BLOB` values are treated as binary strings (byte strings). They have no character set, and sorting and comparison are based on the numeric values of the bytes in column values.

So all the usual string functions work on blobs. In particular, you can use [`substring`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to grab just part of of a blob.

That said, storing a multi-gigabyte data file in a relational database as a BLOB isn't the best thing to do. You'd be better off storing the file's metadata in the database and leaving the file itself in the file system; file systems are pretty good at managing files, relational databases are good at handling structured data.

Comment: I know it's not the best option, but with mysql you get a lot of flexibility: MySQL supports clustering, so you can distribute files among servers. You can backup your database and restore. Also, database handles locking automatically. Times ago I wrote a software to handle a vast number of files following the method you described: it was a waste of time because for every operation you had to check if the files was there, if it was locked, if the system is performing operations on it. Backup and restore were a pain because you had to have the database in sync with the file system and so on...

Comment: @hkproj: I'm not saying that it is a crime to stuff it all into the database, it just isn't necessarily the best first choice. OTOH, you've clearly thought this through and learned your lessons the hard way (which is pretty much the only way to learn the important things); this sort of thing usually comes down to choosing which sort of pain you want to deal with. I just thought I'd mention it in case you were about to make a mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I think i'll be using MySQL this time, just to try...xD. If it doesn't scale well, i'll return back to filesystems...As for scalability I found a few distributed filesystems and considering the cluster option offered by MySQL, so currently I'm just designing the best solution for this software (in terms of cost/time/hardware). More suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach. Store the meta data of your files (like path, name, etc.) in the database and store the files under a directory.
From the database you can fetch the filepath and the read the file in random access mode. Using the file-offset you can get the required subset of the stored data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use e.g. MID() [1] to cut portions of the BLOB; though I would prefer to store files in the file system, not in a database. MySQL performs rather poor on BLOBs.

[1]
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_mid