# MySQL get blob N bytes

Tags: mysql

I'd like to know if you can query a blob (large/medium any kind) column and retrieve the bytes from N to M so you can query a huge blob file and only get small chunks of it in your resultset. If this is possible in MySQL, how can you do it (an example please!)?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154615/select-a-portion-from-a-mysql-blob-field) for plain text but what about doing the same for bytes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the answer right here: [MySQL blob: how to get just a subset of the stored data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6545557/4375900)

> MySQL treats [blobs the same as strings (more or less)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6545557/4375900):
>
> `BLOB` values are treated as binary strings (byte strings). They have no character set, and sorting and comparison are based on the numeric values of the bytes in column values.
>
> So all the usual string functions work on blobs. In particular, you can use [`substring`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) to grab just part of of a blob.
>
> That said, storing a multi-gigabyte data file in a relational database as a BLOB isn't the best thing to do. You'd be better off storing the file's metadata in the database and leaving the file itself in the file system; file systems are pretty good at managing files, relational databases are good at handling structured data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I agree, not the best idea to store big files in there but if that's already what's implemented, well...