# How to get just a subset of a blob

Tags: mysql, substring, blob

The same question has been asked here: [MySQL blob: how to get just a subset of the stored data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545422/mysql-blob-how-to-get-just-a-subset-of-the-stored-data).
However, the provided solution does not work, neither `SUBSTRING` nor `MID` are working properly with **BLOB** datatypes. Did I miss something with this query: `SELECT SUBSTRING(file, 12, 48) FROM log WHERE id=8`, The subset starts at position 1 and the length is somewhat to 48.
Thank you.

Comment: Subset starts at 12 in query not 1?

Comment: QueryA: SELECT SUBSTRING(data, 12, 48) FROM file WHERE id=2138 leads to 0xe2e3cfd30a332030206f626a0a3c3c202f54797065202f58... QueryB: SELECT SUBSTRING(data, 1, 48) FROM file WHERE id=2138 leads to 0x255044462d312e330a2520e2e3cfd30a332030206f626a0a... there is somewhat a shift, but I don't see the logic. Thank you mike

Answer (score 0):

The `SUBSTRING` function seems to work fine for me on `VARBINARY` and `BLOB`, at least in MariaDB 5.6.20:

```
MySQL [gps]> show create table KV \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: KV
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `KV` (
  `kv_key` varbinary(767) NOT NULL,
  `kv_value` longblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`kv_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL [gps]> select HEX(kv_key), HEX(kv_value) from KV where kv_key > x'99' limit 10;
+--------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| HEX(kv_key)                                            | HEX(kv_value)          |
+--------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| FC0696FC1A4AD423B65465FC3D7BBBAFCBDCD8FC657A8BB203FE0F |                        |
| FC114A8CF4C01BD7                                       | 01FE589B5E0200         |
| FC114A8CF4C01BD7FCC991                                 | 55414200               |
| FC114AF271B994BF                                       | 01FE589B5E0200         |
| FC114AF271B994BFFCC991                                 | 434F50442050696C6F7400 |
| FC1A4AD423B65465                                       | 01FE589B5E0200         |
| FC1A4AD423B65465FC2550FCB7D4D490FCA2E4                 |                        |
+--------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL [gps]> select HEX(SUBSTRING(kv_key, 4, 4)), HEX(kv_value) from KV where kv_key > x'99' limit 10;
+------------------------------+------------------------+
| HEX(SUBSTRING(kv_key, 4, 4)) | HEX(kv_value)          |
+------------------------------+------------------------+
| FC1A4AD4                     |                        |
| 8CF4C01B                     | 01FE589B5E0200         |
| 8CF4C01B                     | 55414200               |
| F271B994                     | 01FE589B5E0200         |
| F271B994                     | 434F50442050696C6F7400 |
| D423B654                     | 01FE589B5E0200         |
| D423B654                     |                        |
+------------------------------+------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MySQL [gps]> select HEX(kv_key), HEX(SUBSTRING(kv_value, 4, 4)) from KV where kv_key > x'99' limit 10;
+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| HEX(kv_key)                                            | HEX(SUBSTRING(kv_value, 4, 4)) |
+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| FC0696FC1A4AD423B65465FC3D7BBBAFCBDCD8FC657A8BB203FE0F |                                |
| FC114A8CF4C01BD7                                       | 9B5E0200                       |
| FC114A8CF4C01BD7FCC991                                 | 00                             |
| FC114AF271B994BF                                       | 9B5E0200                       |
| FC114AF271B994BFFCC991                                 | 44205069                       |
| FC1A4AD423B65465                                       | 9B5E0200                       |
| FC1A4AD423B65465FC2550FCB7D4D490FCA2E4                 |                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```